# Is it possible to run python38 venv on python37 or python310?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, virtual-environment

My project supports Python37 and Python 310. One library (a2ba_sdk) that I will need to use only supports Python38. Is it possible to create virtual environment for this library and can run it from python37 or python310.

What I am looking for here is to work with multiple version of python.

Comment: If the library contains a binary extension compiled for Python 3.8 specifically, it is not possible to use it with another Python version.

Comment: What prevents your project to support Python3.8?  It runs on Python3.7 and Python3.10.

Comment: The first comment is only true if the binary was compiled using parts of the python API that are specific to 3.8

Comment: @MichaelButscher - Thanks. This gives answer to my question.

Comment: @S.B - We are migrating our code from 37 to 310. We don't want one more stop in between our migration.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven To call any function of the API, the extension must dynamically link the specific library or executable of the Python 3.8 runtime with the appropriate filename. Of course you can try to modify the extension to link to another file or try other things but this is not reliable.